# How can I find the temp file?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, nano

I was going to get it to work by creating a temporary file, print the name to the screen, using the brace expansion to make it quickly by creating a backup file with the .BAK suffix in the same directory, using the ls for both files, and delete both files:

```
#!/bin/bash

fileone=$(mktemp)
echo cp "$fileone"{,.bak}
ls "$fileone"*
rm -rf "$fileone"*
```

I got an error that tells me that it did not find "/tmp/tmp.UQxlOPQXri.BAK" in my output.

Here's what I got when I run it

```
++ mktemp
+ fileone=/tmp/tmp.CYQY3BP693
+ echo cp /tmp/tmp.CYQY3BP693 /tmp/tmp.CYQY3BP693.bak
cp /tmp/tmp.CYQY3BP693 /tmp/tmp.CYQY3BP693.bak
+ ls /tmp/tmp.CYQY3BP693
/tmp/tmp.CYQY3BP693
+ rm -rf /tmp/tmp.CYQY3BP693
```

Comment: It's quite unclear what you are trying to accomplish, and what your question is?

Comment: How can I fix an error that it did find /tmp/ file?

Comment: i've got no idea what that echo cp does.

Comment: If you're running this with `/bin/sh`, not bash, then `{,.bak}` is treated as part of the filename, and it should be no surprise that no file exists with that name. Brace extension is bash extension, so it only works if you actually use bash (not /bin/sh) to run your script.

Comment: **However**, you aren't actually showing us how you start the script (or including a shebang line like `#!/bin/sh` or `#!/bin/bash`), so the above is all pure speculation, and the question isn't sufficiently detailed/complete to permit a proper answer.

Comment: Again. **How do you actually start your script?**. If you run `sh yourscript` (as opposed to `bash yourscript` or `./yourscript`), then the fact that you use `#!/bin/bash` as the first line does nothing at all.

Comment: I use ./test.sh to run it

Comment: There's no error included in your logs (which show an invocation with `bash -x`, it looks like). We'd need to actually see an error to be able to diagnose it. (An *exact* error -- differences like `.bak` vs `.BAK` are pertinent).

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

fileone=$(mktemp)
echo cp "$fileone"{,.bak}
ls "$fileone"*
rm -rf "$fileone"*
```

You generate a temp file, echo what a cp would do, but you never do it. 
That's all.